# Whether it is possible to use two activities with same layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Whether it is possible one layout can be called by two activities.

Say i have a textview and a button.
1) Using one activity i set the textView with a name 
2) Using another activity, is it possible to display popup message when i click the button.

first activity should set the textview alone and second activity should be called when i click the button. Because, i will get the text from api webservice call in first activity and will display message in popup window using another activity using some other api webservice call.

Comment: Answering your first line question, it is possible and i don't understand what you mean in second line

Comment: I have a one layout file main.xml which has a textview and button, if i click on the button some popup window should open. The question is whether i can use second activity to display popup window for the same layout.

Comment: yes why not, just create a xml for popup window and then use that in second activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use one layout for two activities,but in that case where you use same controls for both activites:

like activity one:
uses both one textView and Button

like activity two:
uses both one textView and Button

Comment: But first activity should set the textview alone and second activity should be called when i click the button. Because, i will get the text from api webservice call in first activity and will display message in popup window using another activity using some other api webservice call.

Comment: @user3128481 you are confusing us. Please edit your question and explain completely what you want.

Comment: it doesn't matter that,for what purpose you are using the same layout,also i have played many times with same layout for different purposes, so don't worry about that,it will not create any issue or exception.

Comment: if this answer solved your question,then mark it as answer by clicking on tick mark to the left side of the answer, for others help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Two activities don't care if they are using the same layout, and in fact don't really know about it. You can use view.setVisibility to make certain views invisible or visible, and as long as you are using the ids associated with the views can make different calls on them in the activities.

So the answer is yes, you can manipulate that layout however you like in two different activities.

Answer (score 1):

No problem, you can easily use same layout file for more then one activity.
First try to implement this thing in your project, and then see, what happening.

Thanks,
Sumeet.